# UIView flexible height with NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm adding some views to my `UIViewController` in code and using `NSLayoutConstraints` to position them where I want them on screen. Being a little new to NSLayoutConstraints in code; I did a test setup and am 95% of the way there. This is my current code:

```
UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:redView];

    [redView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:nil attribute:0
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:100]];

    [redView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:nil
                                                        attribute:0
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:693]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:60]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];


    UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:blueView];
    [blueView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:0
                                                        multiplier:10
                                                          constant:50]];

    [blueView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil attribute:0
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:693]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:redView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1 constant:70]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:redView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];


    UIView *orangeView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    orangeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:orangeView];
    [orangeView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:nil
                                                           attribute:0
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:25]];

    [orangeView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:nil
                                                           attribute:0
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:693]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:25]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];
```

Which looks like this - as I want it: (Ignore the grey background - thats the superView) 
[image: Which looks like this]

Now what I am trying to do is get the `orangeView`s height to fill the rest of the screen to the bottom of the `superView`. However when I add a bottom constraint to the orangeView it adjusts the other views heights, too.

How can I get the orange views height to fill the grey area below it?

Edit:

Removing the height constraint on the `orangeView` and adding a bottom constraint to the superview like this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];
```

Changes the views like so:

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the orange view's height constraint when you added the bottom to superview constraint?

Comment: @Leonardo Yeah I tried that; see my updated question for what happens when I do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a fixed height on the orange view, so how can it expand and fill the entire view ?

Also I suggest you pin the top of the view to the bottom of the previous view, since you can easily change view sizes and keep the spacing even, when you do so, else you will have to adjust your constants in the bottom to bottom relationship.

Here is a code that does work fine:

```
UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] init];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:redView];

[redView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:0
                                                   multiplier:1
                                                     constant:100]];

[redView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:0
                                                   multiplier:1
                                                     constant:693]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:60]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];


UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:blueView];
[blueView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:nil
                                                     attribute:0
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:50]];

[blueView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:nil attribute:0
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:693]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:redView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1 constant:10]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:redView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];


UIView *orangeView = [[UIView alloc] init];
orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
orangeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:orangeView];

[orangeView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:0
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:693]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:blueView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:25]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:blueView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. I originally tried to pin the next view to the bottom of the previous, except I used bottom / bottom relationship and not top / bottom - didn't have full understanding of the code. But now I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to set `Y constraints` to orange view: set bottomLayout constraint and vertical spacing for blue view. If XCode warn you with orange warnings, read those warnings, it usually says something lile "you need X constraint for your view".

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[yourViewHere(300)]-50-|"
options:0
metrics:nil
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(yourViewHere)]];
```

Where `(300)` is width of your view. That code snipper set constraint from bottomLayout to your view. Add similiar constraints as described above.